# No such module `Quick` using cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, cocoapods

I've been learning swift for three days. I'm planning to build my skill in swift especially in iOS development. I just advised by my colleague who is an iOS developer to learn swift while writing test in our app -- this is for the benefit to the company and myself which it makes sense for me. Now, I'm trying to follow this tutorial 
 https://medium.com/@ynzc/getting-started-with-tdd-in-swift-2fab3e07204b

After following the tutorial to rewrite the test in a framework called Quick which is very similar with Rspec. I did the installation of the CocoaPod then follow the install of the Quick framework. Use the `.xcworkspaces` instead of the `.xcodeproj`. But still I'm getting the error of `No such module 'Quick'`.

I did research already and removing the pods but still getting the error.

```
platform :ios, '9.2'

target 'FizzBuzz' do
  use_frameworks!

  def test_pods
    pod 'Quick', '~> 0.9.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 3.2.0'
  end

  target 'FizzBuzzTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    test_pods
  end

  target 'FizzBuzzUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    test_pods
  end

end
```

screenshot of the project folder:
[image: screenshot of the project folder]

Answer (score 7):

I recently had this issue and none of the current answers solved this for me.

The reason I was getting this error was that the Test/Spec file (NetworkSpec.swift) that I had  created had a target membership of the main application target, not the tests target.

To update this, I opened the project in xcode, selected the file in the project explorer and then in the properties window on the right hand side. Then in the target membership area. I had two options.

- ProjectName
- ProjectNameTests

I unchecked the checkbox next to ProjectName (not the app's real name) and then checked the one next to ProjectNameTests and re-ran the tests. Everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. I did not need to nest the test targets in my podfile. e.g.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'MyAppName' do
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'MyAppNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
end

target 'MyAppNameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0' # or '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Xcode 8.1. Click on the currently selected scheme.

Select 'manage schemes'.

[Selected scheme.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAJks.png)

Put check mark next to test schemes and Quick.

Click on your app scheme again. Select each scheme and go to Product > Build. Finally select your main app scheme again. Now try adding 'import Quick' in one of your test classes.

[Schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Dfs.png)

Answer (score 2):

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

I was getting same issue. Files within Test folder did not see Nimble and Quick pods despite my Podfile was configured correctly and Target Membership for my test file set up correctly as well. I was unable to import both Pods.

Running below commands on Project folder via CLI resolved issue for me.

```
$ pod update Quick
$ pod update Nimble
```

My **Podfile** implementation of both pods for reference:

```
def include_test_pods
  pod 'Quick'
  pod 'Nimble'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Cocoapods may need to be rebuilt.

1. Quit XCode. Go to terminal and cd into your project.
2. Run pod deintegrate.
3. Run pod install.
4. Open Xcode and clean and build your .xcworkspaces project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply man but it didn't worked for me. Still keep issuing the error `No such module 'Quick'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue that persisted through build cleans. I noticed that it was only happening in one file and files that did not have this issue had `import foundation`. After importing foundation on the line before it, it then worked. I thought maybe it was simply modifying the file that had done it so I removed the foundation import and the error came back.  So try adding that import if you do not have it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first you just need to use pod inside your target project, so it gona share for your test target like that

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TestNetWorkLayer' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Quick'
  pod 'Mockingjay'
  pod 'Nimble'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'

  target 'TestNetWorkLayerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
      end
end
```

After that you can import it inside your project

```swift
import Quick
import Nimble
class NativeApiClientSpec{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `Podfile` i use smth like this:

```
target 'Specs' do
  pod 'Quick'
  pod 'Nimble'
  shared_pods
end
```

Additionally, re-open the project or use the following command: `Product -> Clean and build folder`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. After a lot of trial and error, I found fix here: https://github.com/Quick/Quick/issues/402#issuecomment-149459840. I had to delete derived data and regenerate project to get Quick as build scheme

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

1. Close xcode project
2. Run `$ pod deintegrate`
3. Delete `Podfile.lock`
4. Run `$ pod install`

and Build again!